# iOS webview gets stuck in a scroll state and JavaScript doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, scrollbar

I'm finding that I'm having problems with iOS webviews. I have a webview which is longer than my ipod4's screen, so I can scroll up and down. If I quickly drag and tap on the screen for a few seconds, I will get into the state where the scroll bar on the right stays permanently on the screen. Once this happens, if I drag the screen in any direction, the page no longer has any momentum and I can no longer flick the page. I.e., it stays in the exact same position once I take my finger off the screen.

I also find while it's in this state that I can drag the page further off the screen (to a point where it would usually bounce back), and it no longer bounces back. The screen capture I have included is an image of my white page after being dragged up, and the scroll bar being stuck on the screen.

The only way of getting out this locked scroll bar state is too zoom on the webpage with two fingers.

I have a button which also doesn't perform it's javascript function when in this state.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to consistently reproduce this state, so tapping and dragging in quick succession is the best reproduction I have.

[image: Screenshot of Auth dialog]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your webviews should ever be inside a scrollable area because websites themselves need to scroll as well. I would suggest that you use autolayouts to attach the webview to whatever the size of the container it's contained is in and let it figure out if and how to scroll itself.

A webview is really an app in an app and should be treated a bit differently than the rest of your app.